# ignore nonexistent columns in the model

Tags: model, sequelize.js

I have a website, which will have different database, some will have more tables, others less, I would like to know if some way to ignore these checks in the sequelize, in my model I have 5 columns in users, in my case database has 6, or 7, it doesn't give an error

[this error occurs when I have this column in the bank but I don't have it in the model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Pnb.png)

is there any way to ignore it, or add a default value for it?

Comment: i hope this [link](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4074) helps

Comment: @gowridevyes, that would work but on the controller side, to do a search or something, I mean the model itself, it checks the columns of my database, and if it doesn't have any model, it can't add a value, I wanted it to be automated, that if I only had like 5 columns defined in the model, he would not try to check the ones that are not there.